# What flowering plant is this?

Tags: identification, flowers

We bought this flowering plant from Home Depot but forgot its name. Does anyone know what this is?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On current showing, it looks like a Chrysanthemum variety, but it seems very early for one of those to be showing flower buds at this time of year (if you're in the Northern hemisphere) unless its been forced. Another pic when it's in flower would confirm or deny this ID.

The other possibility, and this one is a little more likely to be about to flower, is Tanacetum parthenium, or Feverfew, previously classed as Chrysanthemum, but not usually sold as a large plant like this. Again, open flowers would decide.

Comment: When I bought it, it wasn't this big. It was in a much smaller pot. The plant is healthy after transferring it to a bigger pot and moving it outside for sun. I'm thinking of planting this in the soil instead of the pot but want to know under what conditions it will survive before I do that. And yes, I do live in the pacific NW.

Comment: I think I see a flower bud top right in the pic - - if it is, wait till it opens up or at least begins to show itself, to confirm ID.